# Django - Submit multiple forms with one submit button

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-queryset

I'm trying to create a check in page that lists all of the people that have signed up. Each person has an input box that submits the number of hours they were at the event. I want it so that the same form is submitted multiple times for every person; I don't want to have a submit button for every person because there will be several people and it'll be tedious. I'm using a for loop `{% for signups in signup %}` to loop through the queryset for the people who are signed up.

Here's a screenshot to illustrate:[image]

In the backend, I want it to save the number of hours to the row in the queryset with the matching name.

HTML:

```
<form action="/events/occ_checkin" class="form" method="POST" id="checkin_{{ signups.id }}" name="checkin_{{ signups.id }}">{% csrf_token %}
    {% for form in formset %}
    <h5>
    <label for="{{ form.fullname.id_for_label }}">***how would I get the attendee's name?***</label>
    <input id="{{ form.fullname.id_for_label }}" name="{{ form.fullname.html_name }}" type="hidden" value="***attendee's name here as well***">
    <input id="{{ form.hours.id_for_label }}" name="{{ form.hours.html_name }}" step="0.01" type="number" class="form-control" value="{{ events.hours }}">
    </h5>
    {% endfor %}
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/  specifically might wanna check out. ModelFormset.

Comment: Okay. I've tried using formsets, but can't figure out a way for it to display the names of the attendees of the event. I was using a for loop to iterate through the attendees  `{% for signups in signup %}{{ signups.fullname }}*form stuff*{% endfor %}`. But because I'm using `{% for form in formset %}` I can't think of a way to get the names of each attendee without them repeating several times. I've edited my question to have my current html code.

Comment: In the model form you can access the associated model through the 'instance' attribute if I'm not mistaken. This is off the top of my head but the django documentation surely could confirm.

Comment: I'm trying to get the variable `{{ signups.fullname }}` for the specific iteration of the for loop in html, how would I do that? HTML is in my question.

Comment: I figured out a way: `{% for signups in signup %}{% if forloop.parentloop.counter == forloop.counter %}{{ signups.fullname }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}`

Answer (score 0):

Using `modelformset_factory` worked.

HTML:

```
<form action="/events/occ_checkin" class="form" method="POST" id="checkin_{{ signups.id }}" name="checkin_{{ signups.id }}">{% csrf_token %}
    {% for form in formset %}
    <h5>
    <label for="{{ form.fullname.id_for_label }}">{% for signups in signup %}{% if forloop.parentloop.counter == forloop.counter %}{{ signups.fullname }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}</label>
    <input id="{{ form.fullname.id_for_label }}" name="{{ form.fullname.html_name }}" type="hidden" value="{% for signups in signup %}{% if forloop.parentloop.counter == forloop.counter %}{{ signups.fullname }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}">
    <input id="{{ form.hours.id_for_label }}" name="{{ form.hours.html_name }}" step="0.01" type="number" class="form-control" value="{{ events.hours }}">
    </h5>
    {% endfor %}
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

For views.py and forms.py I just followed the documentation on formsets.